Bash script to open a link passing token
What's the Ubuntu version of open -target-id $1 -- -W http://{{ADDRESS}} -token env://TOKEN? I've tried using xdg-open but that doesn't take parameters.
Update:
The full function that I'm trying to adjust is
function brmq() {     
    export BOUNDARY_TOKEN=$(authenticate)     
    boundary connect -exec open -target-id $1 -- -W  http://{{boundary.addr}} -token env://BOUNDARY_TOKEN }

Note that this uses the boundary for ubuntu and every command related to boundary works fine. The only issue I have is that boundary wants to run this command, but open does not exist in ubuntu and xdg-open does not take parameters.
The original command was for macOS and it's Ubuntu 20.04.

Where's the open coming from? Windows, other *nix, macOS?

It's coming from macOS and Ubuntu 20.04. Will edit the question

-target-id and -token are not mentioned in macOS' open man page, are those arguments passed down to the application (I suppose a browser)? Which browser? What do you pass as an argument to the script ($1) on macOS? I suppose token would be a header that's added to the request to perform some sort of authentication?

Normally on Unix systems -- signals the end of the options, so I suppose -target-id is in fact an option to open, although it doesn't appear to be listed on its man page.

I did not write the script, I inherited it and trying to change it so that it will run on my machine. The idea is to open the website at ADDRESS and directly log in to the service with TOKEN.

Have you ever run the script? If so, you probably called the script with something like ./script something, or /path/to/script something, or bash /path/to/script something etc; what's that something? In which browser is the page opened? To me at least, it's unclear what token does exactly: it could be a custom header, a query parameter, an alias for the Authorization header and so on, so knowing what's going to crunch that argument is crucial I think. Can you post the full script, redacting private stuff? Maybe it'd make things a little easier

@user68186 The thing is she has this token thing which is inherited from the environment, which apparently is used to authenticate to the backend. She'll probably need to pass additional headers / query parameters in the request I think

I mean this is not really private, it's just trying to open RMQ inspection in browser with boundary. It will take the system default browswer. -W keeps the window open.
function brmq() {     export BOUNDARY_TOKEN=$(authenticate)     boundary connect -exec open -target-id $1 -- http://{{boundary.addr}} -token env://BOUNDARY_TOKEN }

So the script is not running open, it's running boundary. That's important information, and you should add this information, along with the whole script to the question.

That being said, I don't know this boundary thing, but the thing is: this is going to be a hard one, as the script (which is in fact just an excerpt of the script I guess as it's just a function) appears to be doing way more than just opening a webpage, in fact it appears to be going through some token generation by calling authenticate etc. The script would need to be fully ported to Ubuntu. if I'm correct, unless you install this boundary thing on your system, replicating the exact authentication process will require at the very least replicating the token generation thing.

@Darina Could you please update your question rather than provide additional information in comments? The comments are our channel to ask you for clarification. They are not meant for extended discussions. As an original questioner, you should always update your question with the new information.

I've edited the original question with the full function, but boundary itself has an ubuntu version and all other parts of this script run correctly.

Just call your browser directly? firefox or chromium-browser or google-chrome-stable or whatever ... though I don't know if any of those accept a -token env://something argument
